# podman CentOS 8 not starting container as non-root user

Tags: centos8, podman

I am trying to start busybox container as non root on CentOS 8 server, but its giving the below message.

What is the correct way to start the container as non-root user?

```
  podman run -it --name busy  docker.io/library/busybox sh
Trying to pull docker.io/library/busybox...Getting image source signatures
Copying blob bdbbaa22dec6 done
Copying config 6d5fcfe5ff done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
ERRO[0003] Error pulling image ref //busybox:latest: Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:bdbbaa22dec6b7fe23106d2c1b1f43d9598cd8fc33706cc27c1d938ecd5bffc7": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): there might not be enough IDs available in the namespace (requested 65534:65534 for /home): lchown /home: invalid argument
Failed
Error: unable to pull docker.io/library/busybox: unable to pull image: Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:bdbbaa22dec6b7fe23106d2c1b1f43d9598cd8fc33706cc27c1d938ecd5bffc7": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): there might not be enough IDs available in the namespace (requested 65534:65534 for /home): lchown /home: invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the command you run is correct. On my Fedora 31 system it works just fine.

```
[testuser@fedora31 ~]$ podman run -it --name busy docker.io/library/busybox sh
Trying to pull docker.io/library/busybox...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob bdbbaa22dec6 done  
Copying config 6d5fcfe5ff done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
/ # exit
[testuser@fedora31 ~]$ podman --version
podman version 1.8.0
[testuser@fedora31 ~]$
```

The flag `--rm` is also often useful.

It seems the error you get is related to the UID mapping.

Here is some information regarding running "rootless" podman:

https://github.com/containers/libpod/blob/master/docs/tutorials/rootless_tutorial.md

What also might be interesting:

"*Does not work on NFS or parallel filesystem homedirs*"

Quote from

https://github.com/containers/libpod/blob/master/rootless.md

Comment: thanks for the pointer, my issue with UID. not `podman` is production ready.